# How can I get all images from a qrc file?

Tags: qt, qcombobox, resource-file

I want to get all images from my qrc file and pass them to a ComboBox.
Don't know what to say more. It's a very basic task I think but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should get you on the right track:

```
foreach( const QString &imageName, QDir(":").entryList() )
{
    myCombBox->addItem( imageName );
}
```

This is if all of your images are at the root of your resource file.  If they're namespaced then replace `":"` with `:/image_namespace`

Either way, the `":"` is treated as an actual directory containing all of your resources and is accessible in the same way as your file system.

Comment: Did this work? QDir should not be able to iterate on resources.

Comment: Why not? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html "It can also be used to access Qt's resource system."